# how to filter multiple data on multiple column sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, filtering

i want to filter multiple data such as

id = "1,3,5" from columnid which is having 1 to 10 id

and another column such as name

name = "a,e,d" from name column of 10 records

and another criteria such as age

age = "21,23,20" from age column of 10 records from same table,
one example i got is

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("TABLE_NAME",new String[]{"ColumnName"}, "ColumnName=?",new String[]{"value"}, null, null, null);
```

which is just for one column but i want to get data from multiple column, can anyone help me?

Comment: better u ask your database related question in stackexchange

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar No, it's appropriate here. Because it's programming-related (Android implementation of the query method).

Comment: If you were to use normal SQL (i.e.: the `rawQuery()` method), I'd suggest something like `SELECT SomeField, SomeOtherField FROM SomeTable WHERE id IN (1, 3, 5) AND Age IN (21, 23, 30) AND Name IN ('a', 'e', 'd')`. I'm sure there is an equivalent by using the `query()` method. But I prefer pure SQL.

Comment: Ok let me try @Rotwang

Comment: Thank you @Rotwang

Comment: Do u have any other option @Rotwang

Comment: The other option is to study how exactly the `query()` method works. Or go something further and study **Views** (which are virtual tables generated by stored queries).

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If not, please provide a [mcve], with a `.dump`from SQLite command line tool of a suitably tailored toy database; and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this working example,

```
Cursor cursor =
                db.query(TABLE_DIARYENTRIES,
                        new String[] {},
                        STUDENT_ID + " IN ("+resultStudent+")"+ " AND " +CLASS_NAME + " IN ("+resultClass+")"
                                + " AND " +SUBJECT_NAME + " IN ("+resultSubject+")"
                        null, null, null, null);
```

and your result string should be 'a','b','c'

Answer (score 0):

I really like the way [Google's example](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#java) is structured. Because for noobies such as myself it makes it really clear what I am doing. And it is also more robust to SQL injections. Here is my modified version of the Google example:

```
//Column(s) I want returned
String[] projection = {"ColumnIWantReturned"};

//Column(s) I want to filer on
String selection = "FilterColumn1 IN (?) and FilterColumn2 IN (?, ?)";
String[] selectionArgs = {"ArgumentForFilterColumn1", "FirstArgumentForFilterColumn2", "SecondArgumentForFilterColumn2"};

Cursor cursor = db.query(
        "MyTable",   // The table to query
        projection,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
        selection,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
        selectionArgs,          // The values for the WHERE clause
        null,                   // don't group the rows
        null,                   // don't filter by row groups
        null               // The sort order
);

cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    Log.d("this-is-a-test", cursor.getString(0));
    cursor.moveToNext();
}

cursor.close();
```